# Magento 2 How to set Config Provider for all pages?

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, data-provider

I created one module. which have helper function which returns module is enabled or not? Now I want to check if this module is enabled or not in javascript for all pages on the frontend, for that, I want to set function value to config provider like **"window.checkoutConfig.customvalue"**. Now I need like "**window.catalog.customvalue**" or any global javascript value which can be accessed from every page, How can I do this?

**One more example for global config is "BASE_URL" when you write BASE_URL in the console it gives URL, I want the same functionality, just need to add that kind of variable in config.**

I know how to set config provider in the checkout with "chckoutConfig" but I want to set that function value in common config provider so I can get that value in every js file or console.

If anyone has an idea about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magento 2 has "head.additional" block, where you can set your variables globally.

Add below code in 

```
app\code\Name\Module\view\frontend\templates\globalvar/globalvariable.phtml
```

```
?php
$globalConfig = [];
$globalConfig['FirstVariable'] = 'My first value';
$globalConfig['SecondVariable'] = 'My second value';
?>
```

> ```
> <script>
>     window.globalConfigData = <?php echo json_encode($globalConfig); ?>;
> </script>
> ```

Then add below code in XML


```
app\code\Name\Module\view\frontend\layout\default.xml
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="globalconfigvariable" template="Name_Module::globalvar/globalvariable.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```